# Page still refreshes with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

HTML:

```
<body>
<form name='sample' id='sample' method='GET' action='followedbutton.php'>
Name:<input type='text' name='username' id='username'><br>
Age:<input type='text' name='userage' id='userage'><br>
Date:<input type='text' name='userdate' id='userdate'><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Go!'>
</form>
</body>
```

JS :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $form = $('#sample');
    $form.submit(function (e) {
        $.GET(url: $(form).attr('action'), data: $(form).serialize(), success: function (result) {
            $('#div').html(result)
        }, 'json');
        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP success page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);    
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ("No mysqli");
        mysqli_select_db($conn, 'sample') or die ("No DB");
$name = $_GET['username'];
$age = $_GET['userage'];
$date = $_GET['userdate'];
$insert = ("INSERT INTO `test` (name, age, date) VALUES ('$name','$age','$date')");
$insert_query = mysqli_query($conn, $insert) or die ("No query");
mysqli_close($conn);
//header('location:followbutton.php');
echo "<script text='javascript'>alert('Ajax');</script>"
 ?>
```

So I'm trying to submit this form WITHOUT refreshing the page. When I submit the form, I get the alert immediately, without a page refresh. But in my Chrome tab I can see that the page is still loading, and eventually (after 5-7 secs or so) the page goes to `followedbutton.php`.

How can I prevent the page from refreshing while still having my info go to `followedbutton.php` ? What in my JS code needs to be changed? Everything works, I just DON'T want the page refresh at all.

I've taken some advice from other users on SO who've asked similar questions yet none of the advice is working for me.

I've taken the advice on this post to change my code to :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var $form = $('#sample');
$form.submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.get( url:$(form).attr('action'), data:$(form).serialize(), success:function(result)  {$('#div').html(result)},'json'); 
  return false;
});
});
</script>
```

But still get the same result unfortunately. And sadly I've yet to learn how to user my JS console for debugging purposes. It's on the list of things to do though.

Comment: Are you including jQuery in the page? Checked the console for errors?

Comment: yea `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Your call to `$.get` still gives a syntax error because of `url:`, `data:`, etc. See my updated answer (or James') for the correct way to call `$.get`.

Comment: And as others have pointed out, when you're working with JavaScript you should always have your browser's development console open. It will give you information about syntax errors and other problems with your code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `$.GET` it is `$.get`.  It is case sensitive.  As a result, your code is blowing up prior to preventing the default behavior so it is submitting.  Once you fix that, you will also find you are using `get` wrong.

Alway check your js console, it would have told you this was the issue.

Proper call to `get`:

```
$.get($(form).attr('action'), 
      $(form).serialize(), 
      function (result) {
            $('#div').html(result)
      }, 
      'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault()` never gets evaluated if you `return` before it:

```
function(e) {
  // ...
  return false;
  e.preventDefault(); // <-- never happens
}
```

There's also a problem with the way you call `$.GET` (which, as others have pointed out, should be `$.get`). It looks like you tried to pass a settings object to `$.get` like you would to `$.ajax`, but there's two problems with your code:

1. You omitted the curly braces around the object (`foo(bar: 1)` is not valid JavaScript; `foo({ bar: 1 })` is), which will result in a syntax error.
2. Even if you fixed that it wouldn't work because unlike `$.ajax`, `$.get` doesn't take a settings object; it takes four separate arguments for `url`, `data`, `success` and `dataType`.

What you actually want, then, is this:

```
$.get( $(form).attr('action'),  // url
       $(form).serialize(),     // data
       function (result) {      // success
         $('#div').html(result)
       },
       'json'                   // dataType
);
```

Comment: True but irrelevant actually.  `return false` also prevents default.

Comment: That's not how get is called, it doesn't take an object as a parameter, it takes 1-4 separate parameters.

Comment: You're right, @JamesMontagne. Annoying that `$.get` and `$.ajax` don't have a consistent API. Regardless, it was a syntax error before.